# iOS: App is generating hundreds of empty albums into the Photos App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, photo

I have an app that allows users to edit the photo in the app and save it into the Photos App.

But, I got a strange issue from some of my app's users.

The app is generating thousands of empty albums into the Photos App.
Please check the below screenshot for more details.

I have checked my code many times, but there is no way to generate multiple albums with the same name.

Here is my code to save the image into the Photos App.

```
    func saveImage(image: UIImage) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                var assetsCollection : PHAssetCollection!

                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", EditingPhotosAlbum.albumName)
                let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
                if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
                    assetsCollection = collection.firstObject!
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                        let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                        let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: assetsCollection)
                        albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset!] as NSArray)

                    }) { (done, error) in
                        if error == nil {
                        }else {
                        }
                    }

                }else {
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: EditingPhotosAlbum.albumName)
                    }) { [weak self] success, _ in
                        if success {
                            self?.saveImage(image: image)
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .denied, .restricted:
                print("Not allowed")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Not determined yet")
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help if anyone has this type of issue.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi @Nikunj please share your code about create photo albums. I think there is a loop somewhere :)

Comment: Hello @EmreCiftci thanks for the answer, please check my code about create photo albums.

Comment: Where do you call `saveImage(image:)` function?

Comment: I am calling saveImage(image: ) in viewDidLoad() of my ViewController.

Comment: before calling the 'saveImage(image:)' function check the existence of the album

Comment: I am checking it inside the 'saveImage(image:)' function.

Comment: Try using "localizedTitle" instead of "title". Otherwise it is always going to else case and creating new album every time the view is loaded. Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions#1965657

Comment: @PankajKulkarni Currently, I am not able to generate this issue from my side, this issue is given by one of our users.

Comment: So Should I try "localizedTitle" instead of "title"?

Comment: Yes, try `localizedTitle`.

Comment: ok, Thanks @PankajKulkarni.

Comment: @Nikunj , did you find solution? Or do you still have this issue?

Comment: I have applied this localizedTitle solution in my app, and haven't get any new user ask this issue

Comment: One of the user is back from empty folders: he has over 250 empty albums in his Apple iPad Pro. Can’t get rid of them and a new album is created  every time he starts the iPad. Most annoying. He said he has sat for hours trying to delete these albums one at a time.